# Can not kill process InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Trying to kill process via InnoSetup installer. But it still shows an error that the processes are running.

I use this.

```
[Files]
Source: Files\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly; BeforeInstall: TaskKill('CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe')

[Code]
procedure TaskKill(fileName: String);
var
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{sys}/taskkill.exe'), '/f /im ' + '"' + fileName + '"', ExpandConstant('{sys}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

or

```
[Code]
procedure TaskKill(fileName: String);
var
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('taskkill.exe'), '/f /im ' + '"' + fileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

Please help

Comment: Did you check the `taskkill` exit code? Did you check what the task kill says?

Comment: Run `taskkill /f /im CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` from cmd work fine and close necessary processes.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl where can I check this? Is there some log file for taskkill.exe ?

Comment: Start with adding `Log('task kill exit code = ' + IntToStr(ResultCode));`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks, I'll try. But I have one .exe installator of my programm. And my .iss file doesn't exist `Log(...)`. Where can find log after run installator ?

Comment: I do not understand you. Add the `Log` call after your `Exec` call. + To enable logging, run the installer with `/LOG=C:\some\path\installer.log` command-line switch.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did what you said, found log file but there is no line with my log `Log('task kill exit code = ' + IntToStr(ResultCode));`. Section `[Setup]` contains `SetupLogging=yes`.

Comment: Works for me. Show us your log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I got it. It does not reach that line in the [Files] where the BeforeInstall is contained. A window with busy process, which was supposed to kill, is shown earlier. Therefore I use my code in InitializeSetup function.